# TBB paralell_for does not copy elements from one array into another one correctly?

Tags: c++, tbb, parallel.for

I want to copy elements from one array into another with custom policy, such as that if element is not zero, then copy it into another. The code may like bellow:

```
double src[NUM] = {a0, a1, a2, ..., an};
double dst[NUM] = {0}; // initialize dst all elements as 0
double twodouble[NUM] = {0};
tbb::atomic<int> count = 0;

// this parallel just want to copy non-zero elements from src int dst
tbb::paralell_for(tbb::blocked_range<szie_t>(0, NUM),
  [&](const tbb::blocked_range<szie_t>& r){
    for (szie_t i = r.begin(); i < r.end(); ++i) {
        if (std::abs(src[i]) < esp) continue;
        dst[count] = src[i];
        twodouble[count] = 2.0 * src[i];
        count++;
}
    
});
```

In fact, the dst elements may like that: [a0, a1, 0, am, ..., 0, a_(count-1)], apparently， some elements that is not zero in src were not copyed into dst.

My pc has 12 CPUs, I take it that parallel_for sub-block range into different CPU to copy elements, so this copy may be thread safe, but really not. What's wrong that code and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using the shared `count` atomic to define the placement order. It causes race conditions because several threads can write to the same memory concurrently. Also, it causes order breaking since there is no guarantee that the first writing operation will be performed for the first `src` element.

To avoid race conditions and copy the data properly you should use the local `blocked_range` indexes not only to get access to `src` but also to `dest`.

The code should be something like the following:

```
tbb::parallel_for( tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, NUM),
  [&](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r) {
    for (size_t i = r.begin(); i < r.end(); ++i) {
      if (std::abs(src[i]) < esp) continue;
      dst[i] = src[i];
      twodouble[i] = 2.0 * src[i];
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: But this will let some index of twodouble not be initiallized, such as that if the src like: 
`src = {1, 0, 2, ...}`, and twodouble should be `twodouble = {2, 4, ...}`. If I do not use global atomic `count`, the twdouble really like:

```
 twodouble[0] = 2;
 twodouble[1] = a not initialized value;
 twodouble[2] = 4;
```